# How to deal withOO//OOP S3 in R

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R, I have coded with Python and here OOP is quite different to python. I am trying to understand it, so in S3 you can create methods/functions that are not directly attached to a single class, just the same as the objects as they can be in multiple classes (which is quite flexible I guess). However what I do not understand is when I am creating a class such as:

```
> my_mean <- function (x, ...) {
UseMethod("my_mean", x)} 
> my_mean
 function (x, ...) {
UseMethod("my_mean", x)}
> my_mean.default <- function(obj){cat("this is a generic function")}
> my_mean.default
function(obj){cat("this is a generic function")}
```

But then when I have to run for example summary:

```
summary.default
function (object, ..., digits, quantile.type = 7) 
{
    if (is.factor(object)) 
        return(summary.factor(object, ...))
    else if (is.matrix(object)) {
        if (missing(digits)) 
            return(summary.matrix(object, quantile.type = quantile.type, 
                ...))
        else return(summary.matrix(object, digits = digits, quantile.type = quantile.type, 
            ...))
    }
    value <- if (is.logical(object)) 
        c(Mode = "logical", {
            tb <- table(object, exclude = NULL, useNA = "ifany")
            if (!is.null(n <- dimnames(tb)[[1L]]) && any(iN <- is.na(n))) dimnames(tb)[[1L]][iN] <- "NA's"
            tb
        })
    else if (is.numeric(object)) {
        nas <- is.na(object)
        object <- object[!nas]
        qq <- stats::quantile(object, names = FALSE, type = quantile.type)
        qq <- c(qq[1L:3L], mean(object), qq[4L:5L])
        if (!missing(digits)) 
            qq <- signif(qq, digits)
        names(qq) <- c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", 
            "Mean", "3rd Qu.", "Max.")
        if (any(nas)) 
            c(qq, `NA's` = sum(nas))
        else qq
    }
    else if (is.recursive(object) && !is.language(object) && 
        (n <- length(object))) {
        sumry <- array("", c(n, 3L), list(names(object), 
            c("Length", "Class", "Mode")))
        ll <- numeric(n)
        for (i in 1L:n) {
            ii <- object[[i]]
            ll[i] <- length(ii)
            cls <- oldClass(ii)
            sumry[i, 2L] <- if (length(cls)) 
                cls[1L]
            else "-none-"
            sumry[i, 3L] <- mode(ii)
        }
        sumry[, 1L] <- format(as.integer(ll))
        sumry
    }
    else c(Length = length(object), Class = class(object), Mode = mode(object))
    class(value) <- c("summaryDefault", "table")
    value
}
<bytecode: 0x000001926eaaf8f8>
<environment: namespace:base>
> summary
function (object, ...) 
UseMethod("summary")
<bytecode: 0x000001926e9ec2c0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

I cannot see the difference in why when you call summary in the console it does not give you the function, it gives you a reference to that object. There's any explanation? Furthermore, is it generic in some way similar to **init**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 classes work nothing like any OOP you may be familiar with from other languages. They are a losely connected set of mechanisms that only work when you stick to certain rules.

```r
x <- 1:11
mean(x)
#> [1] 6
```

This implcitely calls the function `mean.default` because x is a simple atomic vector.

Now we create a method for our own class `evil`

```r
mean.evil <- function( x ) {
  return(666) # always retuns 666 that is why it is evil
}
```

And we convert the vector x to a class `evil`:

```r
class(x) <- "evil" # you can actually do it just like that
```

Now, calling `mean` determines that `x`is of class `evil` and calls the according function.

```
mean(x) # calls mean.evil
#> [1] 666
mean.default(x) # coerces R to use the default method which is still possible
#> [1] 6
```

The reason is that `mean` uses `UseMethod()` which checks the class and tries to find a function that has name with the pattern `mean.[myclass]`. And that is all that happens.

```r
mean
#> function (x, ...) 
#> UseMethod("mean")
#> <bytecode: 0x0000000015812e18>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

In other languages everything is held together by the syntax. S3 mechanisms on the other hand can be used to "approximate" OOP but they can be easily misused. They are simply and effective and appropriate for many use cases in R. If you are interested in more advanced OOP in R I recommend R6 classes.

<sup>Created on 2020-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, It was pretty clear, everything I had a clear idea that S3 is just basically generic functions but i dont know that once you assign a vector to a class R reads it and then decides what to do with the object. Furthermore, what in case we do not use mean as class, we create our own class called evil in which evil.default returns 666, and we create more methods. Assigning objects to our class would be vector(x) <- evil, and invoking a method e.g  evil.person, the class is still evil or person? Because in your example you create first the function mean.evil and then the class.

Comment: There are a few  misunderstanding. 1. There is no class `mean`. `mean` is the method.                              There are many methods to handle different S3 classes. You can get the available methods with `methods(mean)`. Accordingly a method `evil.default` is not associated with a class `evil`. To create methods of an evil class use the pattern `*methodname*.evil`. 2. `vector(x) <- evil` will not work. Check the manual. You can set the `class` with the `class()` function. `vector()` accepts the name of a - what one might call - "implicit" class and creates an according vector.

Comment: You should probably check [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-simple-guide-to-s3-methods/) out.